# Finding k different keys using binary search in an array of n elements

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search, time-complexity

Say, I have a sorted array of n elements. I want to find 2 different keys k1 and k2 in this array using Binary search.

A basic solution would be to apply Binary search on them separately, like two calls for 2 keys which would maintain the time complexity to **2(logn)**.

Can we solve this problem using any other approach(es) for different k keys, k < n ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the real complexity (although it will still be the same big O) by walking the shared search path once. That is, start the binary search until the element you're at is between the two items you are looking for. At that point, spawn a thread to continue the binary search for one element in the range past the pivot element you're at and spawn a thread to continue the binary search for the other element in the range before the pivot element you're at. Return both results. :-)

**EDIT:**

As Oli Charlesworth had mentioned in his comment, you did ask for an arbitrary amount of elements. This same logic can be extended to an arbitrary amount of search keys though. Here is an example:

You have an array of search keys like so:

```
searchKeys = ['findme1', 'findme2', ...]
```

You have key-value datastructure that maps a search key to the value found:

```
keyToValue = {'findme1': 'foundme1', 'findme2': 'foundme2', 'findme3': 'NOT_FOUND_VALUE'}
```

Now, following the same logic as before this EDIT, you can pass a "pruned" `searchKeys` array on each thread spawn where the keys diverge at the pivot. Each time you find a value for the given key, you update the `keyToValue` map. When there are no more ranges to search but still values in the `searchKeys` array, you can assume those keys are not to be found and you can update the mapping to signify that in some way (some `null`-like value perhaps?). When all threads have been joined (or by use of a counter), you return the mapping. The big win here is that you did not have to repeat the initial search logic that any two keys may share.

**Second EDIT:**

As Mark has added in his answer, sorting the search keys allows you to only have to look at the first item in the key range.

Comment: ^ You are correct. You can easily apply this concept to `k` items though. I will update my answer.

Comment: Yeah this is one nice idea ! But, the between element can be one of the keys right, cause binary search cannot tell you about between element !

Comment: ^ I'm not sure what you mean by that. Do you mean the pivot element you're at? You should be checking that anyway before you traverse to a high or low range. You stated that the array is sorted. With binary search, you will visit all relevant entries. You shouldn't miss anything.

Comment: @Vinay : Yeah I was making point about the pivot element.But I got the point. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Each search you complete can be used to subdivide the input to make it more efficient. For example suppose the element corresponding to k1 is at index i1. If k2 > k1 you can restrict the second search to i1..n, otherwise restrict it to 0..i1.

Best case is when your search keys are sorted also, so every new search can begin where the last one was found.

Comment: +1 from me for sorting the search keys as well. Missed that detail in my answer. :-)

Comment: oh.. right right ! keys have to come in sorted order for best case. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can find academic articles calculating the complexity of different schemes for the general case, which is merging two sorted sequences of possibly very different lengths using the minimum number of comparisons. The paper at http://www.math.cmu.edu/~af1p/Texfiles/HL.pdf analyses one of the best known schemes, by Hwang and Lin, and has references to other schemes, and to the original paper by Hwang and Lin.

It looks a lot like a merge which steps through each item of the smaller list, skipping along the larger list with a stepsize that is the ratio of the sizes of the two lists. If it finds out that it has stepped too far along the large list it can use binary search to find a match amongst the values it has stepped over. If it has not stepped far enough, it takes another step.